# How to provide some startup objects when starting/deploying an app to AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine, fixtures

I'm looking at way to easily have objects similar to 'fixtures', but for the real database (or my local host work environment).

For example, let's assume I write a blog app. By default (when I load the app in browser, these objects should already be in datastore), it requires an USER (i.e. first admin). While the mechanism is not specific to `appengine`, I'm interested in this particular case.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not make inserting the fixtures part of your automated deployment process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have some admin page in your app, checking if the required data already exists, and asking the user to press a button to insert it (or doing it automatically without even asking the user).

Comment: If your app is able to get some data from the database, it should also be able to insert data. Just code it yourself, and hard-code the data to insert.